# How to label Venn diagrams with percentages of set sizes in python?

Tags: python, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I am using the *matplotlib_venn.venn2* function to plot four different Venn diagrams in a single figure.

My inputs for the function's subset arguments are sets of strings:

```
    cse_set_ucb = set(['data science','algorithms', 'machine learning',...])

    ece_set_ucb = set(['circuits', 'signals', 'machine learning',....])

    v_ucb = venn2([cse_set_ucb,ece_set_ucb],set_labels=['CSE','ECE'],set_colors=['r','g'])
```

and similarly for v_ucla, v_ucsb, and v_ucsd.

Current Result:

[image]

However, to make the comparison more intuitive, I wanted to show the **percentages inside the Venn diagram** **rather than the set sizes**. Is it possible to do so by some functionality in venn2?

For e.g the first plot would be replaced with:

[image]

The only alternative I can think of now is to do the normalization myself somehow and then feed the subset sizes into the venn2 function, rather than the sets, but I was hoping for a smarter way to do this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an argument **subset_label_formatter** which control labels printed using a function.

```
total = len(set_a.union(set_b))
v1 = venn2(
    [set_a, set_b],
    set_labels=labels_depts,
    set_colors=['red', 'green'],
    subset_label_formatter=lambda x: f"{(x/total):1.0%}"
)
```

[image]

Ref:

1)[Percentages in venn diagrams](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/issues/8)

2)[Add parameter to allow formatting of labels of subset sizes](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/pull/28)

Comment: Hi, man. Is there any way to hide the subset label using `subset_label_formatter` argument?

Comment: I was able to hide the labels by doing: `subset_label_formatter=lambda x:f""`

Answer (score 4):

```
## total and percentage
total = len(set_a.union(set_b))
v1 = venn2(
    [set_a, set_b],
    set_labels=labels_depts,
    set_colors=['red', 'green'],
    subset_label_formatter=lambda x: str(x) + "\n(" + f"{(x/total):1.0%}" + ")"
```

)

[image]